# Flutter bloc: how to test bloc constructor while mocking event calls?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I would like to test if a timer initialized by my constructor effectively calls a specific bloc event.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class ExampleBloc extends Bloc<ExampleEvent, ExampleState> {
  ExampleBloc() : super(ExampleInitial()) {
    on<ExampleEvent>((event, emit) {});
    periodicTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), (timer) async {
      add(ExampleEvent());
    });
  }
  late Timer periodicTimer;

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    periodicTimer.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}

@immutable
class ExampleEvent {}

@immutable
abstract class ExampleState {}

class ExampleInitial extends ExampleState {}
```

To test it, I thought about using a widget test because it would be possible to `tester.pump()` the duration from the timer.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:indaband/example_bloc.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class ExampleBlocMock extends MockBloc<ExampleEvent, ExampleState>
    implements ExampleBloc {}

void registerFallbackValues() {
  registerFallbackValue<ExampleState>(ExampleInitial());
  registerFallbackValue<ExampleEvent>(ExampleEvent());
}

void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    registerFallbackValues();
  });
  group(
    'Test',
    () {
      final bloc = ExampleBlocMock();
      final blocStateController = StreamController<ExampleState>.broadcast();
      when(() => bloc.stream).thenAnswer((_) => blocStateController.stream);

      testWidgets('test periodic timer', (WidgetTester tester) async {
        final bloc = ExampleBloc();
        final widget = BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => bloc,
          child: Container(),
        );
        await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
        await tester.pump(Duration(minutes: 1));
        verify(() => bloc.add(ExampleEvent())).called(1);
        await tester.pump(Duration(minutes: 1));
        verify(() => bloc.add(ExampleEvent())).called(2);
        await tester.pump(Duration(minutes: 1));
        verify(() => bloc.add(ExampleEvent())).called(3);
      });
    },
  );
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to mock only the `.add(...)` call, in order to make the timer available.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong here:

1. Your creating a mock bloc in your test, and it's not being used or verified at all given you're creating a 'real' bloc with the same name.
2. Your `ExampleEvent` isn't emitting a new state on each timer tick, so there's nothing to test or capture.
3. Testing the bloc itself is a unit test, not a widget test. The `bloc_test` package provides a convenient set of utilities to unit test blocs, read the docs.
4. Bloc events/states must implement equality overrides to ensure a new state is emitted after each event, refer to the bloc docs and in-depth tutorials as to how the bloc package works.

Once the above is addressed, you can add test cases around verifying the emitted state is what you expect.

Comment: about 3: is it possible to jump frames in a bloc_test like tester.pump(duration) in a widget test?